# How to convert a dataframe to bytes object in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

When you read the data in binary mode like below, it will give you a bytes object.

But right now I have a pandas dataframe in the workflow, how can i convert it to that exact type so i could pass it to an api request?

I looked up online but cannot find anything. any insights would be appreciated. thanks!

`data = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()`

Comment: " how can i convert it to that exact type so i could pass it to an api request?" You are going to need to elaborate. `bytes` just represents raw bytes. What exactly do you expect from the result of your data frame being converted to bytes? What does the API expect?

Comment: The API expects "text/csv;charset=utf8". In the documentation, it reads the data as ```data = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()```  if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try encoding it using pythons encode() function:

```
data = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()
encoded_data = data.encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: This isnt what the OP is asking AFAIKT, and in any case, `data` *will be a `bytes` object* which doesn't have an `.encode` method... `str` objects do.